# Create virtual host in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am new in JavaEE. I work with eclipse and my workspace is in

> `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\EclipseWorkspace`

.
In my windows hosts file I put a new line like

> 127.0.0.1 my.local.proj

Now the question is, how can I access my index.jsp in my browser.
What do I need to setup in my...

> C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\AppServers\Tomcat8\conf\server.xml

I tried adding in my server.xml:

```
      <Host         
        name="my.local.proj"
        appBase="C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\EclipseWorkspace"
        unpackWARs="true"       
        autoDeploy="true"></Host>
```

What did I missing? Do I need to define a context?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the standard `http://localhost:8080/` URL, or to not define the server's host name in the Eclipse's Server Wizard (see e.g. http://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide/ - Step 3)?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/